# I wanna paginate in class view, but an error happened "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken."

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I wanna implement pagination in ListView in Django. I can rewrite the view in function view, but I wanna know how to do pagination in class view for practice.

What I wanna do here is to get data filtered by logged in user and display them with pagination by 20(doesn't matter the number). For example, if Alex is currently logging in, I wanna display Alex's data from the database paginated by 20.

But, when I wrote the code below, I got an error "Cannot filter a query once a slice has been taken." So, now on the HTML file, there are all users' data like Alex's data, Bob's data, Lisa's data, and all other users' data.

I tried to put `paginate_by = 20` under the get_context_data function, but doesn't work. I even think I may not use paginate_by with get_context_data.

```
class FoodList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
  model = Food
  template_name = 'base/all_foods.html'
  context_object_name = 'foods'
  ordering = ['-created']
  paginate_by = 20
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['color'] = 'red'
    context['foods'] = context['foods'].filter(user=self.request.user)
```

Let me know if I need to put more info.
Any advice is helpful and thank you for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this line `context['foods'] = context['foods'].filter(user=self.request.user)`.

Your `context_object_name = 'foods'`. and you are filtering it after it's sliced by `pagination` in `get_context_data` method.

If you want to filter your `queryset` and still have `pagination`, you can do this:

```
class FoodList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Food
    template_name = 'base/all_foods.html'
    context_object_name = 'foods'
    ordering = ['-created']
    paginate_by = 20

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['color'] = 'red' 
        return context
```

Now it will work fine.

**P.S.** always filter or change your queryset in `get_queryset` method or `queryset` attribute. don't do it in `get_context_data` method.